# Java springboot Specification proximity complex trigonometry query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating an app where user can filter results by many various (optional) filters, one of which is searching by proximity. I  am using org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification to build a query dynamically, based on which parameters are provided, most of which are simple ge/le some integer values.
My where clause: (location_lng/lat are values from the db, where numbers are provided coordinates with the query, and < 10 is a distance)

```
SELECT *
FROM rental 
WHERE(
    6371 * acos(
      cos( radians(52.2477331) ) * cos( radians( location_lat ) )
      *
      cos( radians( location_lng ) - radians(21.0136079) )
      +
      sin( radians(52.2477331) )
      *
      sin( radians( location_lat ) )
    )
  ) < 10
```

Im my backend im querying repository with such method:

```
public Page<RentalDTO> getByCriteria(RentalSearchCriteria cr,
                                         Optional<Integer> page,
                                         Optional<String> sort,
                                         Optional<Integer> size,
                                         Optional<Sort.Direction> order) {
        return rentalRepository.findAll(
                where(
                        priceFrom(cr.getPriceFrom())
                                .and(inProximity(cr.getDist(),cr.getLat(),cr.getLng()))
                                .and(priceTo(cr.getPriceTo()))
                                .and(sizeFrom(cr.getSizeFrom()))
                                .and(sizeTo(cr.getSizeTo()))
                                .and(buildFrom(cr.getBuildFrom()))
                                .and(builtTo(cr.getBuildTo()))
                                .and(roomFrom(cr.getRoomFrom()))
                                .and(roomTo(cr.getRoomTo()))
                                .and(moveInAt(cr.getMoveInTo()))
                                .and(tagsIncluded(cr.getFeatures()))
                ),
                PageRequest.of(
                        page.orElse(0),
                        size.orElse(3),
                        order.orElse(Sort.Direction.ASC),
                        sort.orElse("price"))
        ).map(RentalDTO::createFrom);
    }
```

And Specification (this one empty for now):

```
    public static Specification<Rental> inProximity(Integer distance, Double lat, Double lng) {
        if (distance == null || lat == null || lng == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (root, query, cb) -> {
                return null; // todo 
            };
        }
    }
```

The query uses group by, while other queries don't, but surely there should be some way to make it without it, as I dont need to check the whole table to calculate distance for a specific row, maybe some subqueries or such, not really sure how to tackle this one filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up creating a postgreSQL function, and used the function in the Specification:

```
create or replace function distance(lat double precision, lng double precision, db_lat double precision, db_lng double precision)
  returns double precision as $dist$ 
  begin 
  return 
  6371 * acos(
      cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(db_lat))
      *
      cos(radians(db_lng) - radians(lng))
      +
      sin(radians(lat))
      *
      sin(radians(db_lat))
    );
    
    
    end;
    $dist$ language plpgsql;
```

Springboot:

```
    public static Specification<Rental> inProximity(Double distance, Double lat, Double lng) {
        if (distance == null || lat == null || lng == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (root, query, cb) ->
                    cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                            cb.function("distance", Double.class,
                                    cb.literal(lat), cb.literal(lng), root.get("locationLat"), root.get("locationLng")),
                            distance
                    );
        }
    }
```